# Removing JSON property in array of objects

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON array that I'm cleaning up in Python. I want to remove the `imageData` property:

**data.json**

```
[{"title": "foo", "imageData": "xyz123"},
{"title": "bar", "imageData": "abc123"},
{"title": "baz", "imageData": "def456"}]
```

I am setting up a list comprehension to remove the property, but I'm not sure how to create the variable that focuses on `imageData`:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    clean_data = [ item for item in data if not item['imageData'] ]
    # Write `clean_data` to new json file
```

When I `print` the list comprehension, it returns an empty array. What do I have to correct to get this working properly?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

An easy solution to your problem is deleting the unwanted key in place, with `del`:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    for element in data: 
        del element['imageData']
```

You should add some safety checks, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 18):

If not all the elements have an `imageData` key, then using `del` will cause an `KeyError` exception. You could guard against that by using `pop` with a default:

```
for item in data: 
    item.pop('image', None)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[ item for item in data if not item['imageData'] ]
```

is empty becaus *all* have `imageData`. You are just *testing* for it, not *removing* it.

Loop over `date` and `del item['imageData']` on each `item`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:
`clean_data = [k:v for k,v in data.iteritems() if k != 'imageData']`

Or a dictionary expresion/comprehension if you want a dictionary:
`clean_data = {k:v for k,v in data.iteritems() if k != 'imageData'}`