# Removing JSON property in array of objects with Python + Inverse

Tags: python, json

sample data:

[{"title": "foo", "imageData": "xyz123"},
{"title": "bar", "imageData": "abc123"},
{"title": "baz", "imageData": "def456"}]

this will  delete the unwanted key in place, with del, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167485/removing-json-property-in-array-of-objects-with-python)

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    for element in data: 
        del element['imageData']
```

what is the inverse of this command `del element['imageData']`. So i want to delete everything but the `imageData` key.

Comment: Do you want to write the data back to the json file?

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this:

```
temp = data['imageData']
data.clear()
data['imageData'] = temp
```

The resulting dictionary named `data` will only contain the key `imageData` and its associated value

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with a list comprehension to create a new list with only the element(s) of interest:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    new_data = [{'imageData': element['imageData']} for element in data]
```