# Remove meta data from dictionary Based on Boolean value from Python

Tags: python, dictionary

i want to remove the json data from the list based on the allocation.If **allocation:True** then, that particular josn should remove from the dictionary. 
in the below data **{"paperWidth": "4","allocation": True,"model": "RB3150","connType": ["Lan","Wifi","BlueTooth"],"commandSet": "TVSPOS"}**

so this should remove from my final object.How to do this in python.

```
d = {"allPrinters": [{"models": [{"paperWidth": "4","allocation": True,"model": "RB3150","connType": ["Lan","Wifi","BlueTooth"],"commandSet": "TVSPOS"},{"paperWidth": "4","allocation": False,"model": "RB3151","connType": ["Lan","Wifi"],"commandSet": "TVSPOS"}],"active": True,"make": "TVS","_id": "59e6f670f532eb1260b50cd9"},{"models": [{"paperWidth": "4","allocation": False,"model": "EP3160","connType": ["Lan","Wifi"],"commandSet": "ESCPOS"},{"paperWidth": "4","allocation": True,"model": "EP3161","connType": ["Lan"],"commandSet": "ESCPOS"}],"active": True,"make": "EPSON","_id": "59e6fc8ff532eb1260b50cf4"}]}
```

Thank You,
Ramesh M

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167485/removing-json-property-in-array-of-objects-with-python

and : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606930/delete-an-element-in-a-json-object


and :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201233/how-to-delete-json-object-using-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing JSON property in array of objects with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167485/removing-json-property-in-array-of-objects-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the thing you want to remove is the whole printer or just the model, but this should work for the former case and is simple to convert to the latter (dump the `continue` and replace `d['allPrinters']` with `model`):

```
for i, printer in enumerate(d['allPrinters']):
     for model in printer['models']:
         if model['allocation']:
             d['allPrinters'].pop(i)
             continue
```